# How to have Isabelle output cartouches instead of quotes?

Tags: isabelle, pretty-print

Over the years, Isabelle has been transitioning from using quotes `"..."` to cartouches `‹...›` to wrap types, object logic terms, and notation. As of now (Isabelle 2023), it's still quite inconsistent.

For instance, if I declare a locale:

```
locale graph = 
  fixes edges :: ‹'s ⇒ 's ⇒ bool› 
    (infix ‹↦› 80)
```

... the Isabelle output window shows:

```
locale graph
fixes edges :: "'s ⇒ 's ⇒ bool"  (infix ‹↦› 80)
```

Note that the type is wrapped in `"..."`, the notation in `‹...›`.

It is particularly annoying when using the cool “sketch and explore” feature to generate proof skeletons:

```
[...]
  imports
    "HOL-ex.Sketch_and_Explore"
[...]

lemma ‹reflp (=)›
sketch

--- output ---

proof
  show "(x::'a) = x"
    for x :: 'a
    sorry
qed
```

Now, the pretty printer wraps the terms in `"..."` (and does not wrap the `'a` type at all -_-). But I want proofs to use `‹...›` and the convenience of `sketch` is severely undermined if I have to correct the quotes by hand.

Is there any way to tell Isabelle/HOL to just output everything using `‹...›`?

Comment: [Apparently, the next version of Isabelle will have a feature for this.](https://mailman46.in.tum.de/pipermail/isabelle-dev/2024-March/017850.html)
“Added configuration option `atp_proof_cartouches`, which allows to switch
between cartouches and quotes for printing in sketch, explore, and Isar
proofs generated by sledgehammer.” \o/